# low cpu html5 video encoder configuration

Tags: html5-video, performance-testing, codec

I have a test webpage with a lot of gifs of small size(about 200x300), and I replaced them with html5 videos which I encoded in h264 to save bandwith. But now the page uses much more cpu than when gifs, and maybe it's because I have an Intel gm950 graphic card, just to surf internet. So I wanted to know if it's better to use html5 in this kind of webpage or maybe there are a video encoder configuration which uses low cpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that number of videos it's obvious that you'll experience  low web perfomance because. You should use at least a códec with less compression, that means low cpu usage to decompress. Also flash can be a good alternative in performance